# Tracking topViewController array changes in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I'd like to receive some kind of notification or callback when `topViewController` in `UINavigationController` is changed. Do you have any idea how to do that?

Alternatively, I'd like to track `viewControllers` array changes (from which I can easily get changes of to view controller), but don't have idea how to do that too.

Thanks for all help.